# Updating HTML content after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, cart

We are offering discounts if you buy products in bundle.

The issue is only in the mini-cart.

These are the liquid-variables we are using: `${item.final_price}` and `{item.line_level_total_discount}` in the mini-cart.

The issue we are having is, that we are unable to convert both of them to | money, because when we do that they won't update anymore. So currently it is showing without the "," separator. The Ajax only works when you reload the page.

That's why we went with Javascript, this is the code:

```js
$(document).on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.cart_price span#finalprice').each(function() {
      $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/€/g, ''));
      if ($(this).text().indexOf(',') == -1) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(\d{2})$/, ',$1'));
      }
      $(this).text($(this).text() + ' €');
    });
    $('.upsell_tag span').each(function() {
      $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/€/g, ''));
      if ($(this).text().indexOf(',') == -1) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(\d{2})$/, ',$1'));
      }
      $(this).text($(this).text() + ' €');
    });
  }, 500);
});
```

As you can see it's updating on the live site, but only with a delay, so not in sync, and it is really not a bulletproof solution.

We would be happy if the "," separator would be added directly when the value changes, basically in sync with the other values that are updating. Or the ideal solution would be to somehow be able to convert both of the values to money with ajax, but they should be able to update themselves if needed.

Maybe somebody can help us out. This is the link to the site.

https://wf5rzh5vx8shbwz0-62337712363.shopifypreview.com

I am open to questions.

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout`, that adds a delay of `500`ms?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a timer because there's no method of hooking an event to the AJAX request which populates the data? That would be the best approach to solve what you need.

Comment: Also, the link to your site is showing an error. It would be better if you could add all the relevant HTML and JS to the question,

Comment: I have updated the link, its currently on the live site. Its hard to add all the content, I also not sure what is relevant to solve this. @RoryMcCrossan